# Is it possible to add date picker in Rasa Chatbot?

Tags: nlp, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I am trying to make a chatbot using Rasa for a website where the user will be asked their birth date like the photo I have attached. [image]

Is it possible to add date picker in Rasa? I have already read the documentation but confused about how to customize it for website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date picker or other accessories are possible to add to Rasa and you can include them to your assistant by specifying custom output payloads. However, for that to work, you will need the specific accessory to be implemented in your client first.

For example, Slack has an block datepicker which can then be incorporated to Rasa as follows:

```
responses:
  utter_take_bet:
  - custom:
      blocks:
      - type: section
        text:
          text: "Make a bet on when the world will end:"
          type: mrkdwn
        accessory:
          type: datepicker
          initial_date: '2019-05-21'
          placeholder:
            type: plain_text
            text: Select a date
```

Which chat widget are you using for integrating Rasa on your website?

Comment: For adding date picker, I haven't used any chat widget yet. I was actually confused about how to edit other files along with action.py.

Comment: @MahfuzaMohona I have same type of question please help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74502287/using-datepicker-in-rasa-x